# Page footer split into more sections

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, footer, sections

I know that *Crystal Reports* offers the possibility to split the page footer into sections (section a, section b, ...) that can be printed depending on some conditions. If *condition 1* is *true* then print section a, else section b and so on.

I have to make something similar using *iReport* and I don't know how. I can't find the option to make more sections. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You can put as much *textField*, *frame* and others elements to this band as you want. You can use *textFieldExpression* and *printWhenExpression* expression for determine what you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

To expand and suggest an extension to Alex's comment, you can layout each section you have in mind inside a `frame` in the footer. Then set the `printWhenExpression` for each frame instead of a bunch of elements.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="35abc101-1375-42c5-9f5f-2eb3542ca382">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="footerPrint" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="51">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="c8bef919-0e83-4d72-9b25-1a7e0aa6b82b" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{footerPrint}.equals("1")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="4ad1f177-9e43-4d9f-8f05-012090c33193" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Footer Print: 1]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="c8bef919-0e83-4d72-9b25-1a7e0aa6b82b" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{footerPrint}.equals("2")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="4ad1f177-9e43-4d9f-8f05-012090c33193" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Footer Print: 2]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The frames are set to the same dimensions and rest are set to the exact same x/y coordinates. So essentially they overlap, but if you do the expressions correctly only one will be shown at a time anyway.

Of course the other option is to set the expression for each element, I just find this way to be easier.